# install the PortAudio Python bindings first and pyaudio

Tags: python, python-3.7, pyaudio

when i run my code in windows 10, I encounter this error

```
Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first.
```

i install pyaudio but in install pyaudio I faced with this error

```
ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\epic_r_r\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Epic_R_R\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n7_2px9c\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Epic_R_R\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-klf4pk78\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
ERROR: running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\epic_r_r\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Epic_R_R\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n7_2px9c\\PyAudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Epic_R_R\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-klf4pk78\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Epic_R_R\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n7_2px9c\PyAudio\
```

I installed it from another way, but I do not think it's installed properly

please help me i really need this

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your package is not installed properly so, first of all, undo all the setup you do 
try to uninstall and reinstall using pip

```
python -m pip install pyaudio
```

or you can try using wheel (click [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio) to get wheel file)

```
pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
```

if it is not working then try to install using anaconda

```
conda install -c anaconda pyaudio
```

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem, I discovery that `PyAudio` does not support versions larger than 3.6. You can see the supported versions at this link: [PyAudio](https://pypi.org/project/PyAudio/#files)
To solve this problem, I start using python `3.6.8`.

Available to Download from the official `Python` website.

I hope this helps.